# Consulta sql en Laravel - Mostrar en el .blade

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-blade

tengo una duda estoy haciendo una consulta para mostrar en una tabla, dentro de mi consulta necesito dos datos, la suma del as coronas y el name, el problema que al querer mostrar los datos en el .blade como se muestra en la segunda imagen  no me permite mostrar ambos datos, solo me permite uno ya sea corona o name , ¿Cómo puedo mostrar ambos datos de mi consulta en la tabla?.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código como texto por favor (no como imagen) así todos lo podemos ver y copiar/pegar para escribir una respuesta

Comment: También sería útil que muestres un dump de los datos que llegan a la vista `{{dump($datatable}}`

Answer (score 0):

Al hacer join lo mejor es especificar de que tabla estás sacando el name si es de users intenta en tu select poner t3.name igual en tu groupby espero funcione.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Al momento de hacer `join` estas asignando alias a cada tabla y al momento de hacer el `select` especifica con su alias de que tabla quieres sacar el nombre. Sería algo así:

```
('sum(t2.coronas) as coronas', 't3.name')
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es tan sencillo como esto:

```
return DB::table('users_rutinas AS t1')
   ->selectRaw('SUM t2.coronas) as corona, name')
   ->join('.....')
   ->groupBy('name')
```

El Raw, o selectRaw que es mas corto, es un solo parámetro para poner los campos. El segundo parámetro es para bindings, no para otra columna.